# Failed to open implementation for method added to interface from base class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, abstract-class

I'm using Eclipse Neon.

Basically I'm creating a new interface and adding to it an existing method found in different base class.

I have a class `MyServiceImpl` which extends base class `GeneralServiceImpl` with abstract method `doB`.

I created an interface `GeneralService` for `GeneralServiceImpl` and added also `doB` method:

```
public interface GeneralService {    
    abstract void doB();
}

public class GeneralServiceImpl implements GeneralService {
   @Override
   public void doB() { }
   }
}
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl extends GeneralServiceImpl implements MyService {
     @Override
     public void doC() { }
}
```

And my new interface include expecting to use `GeneralServiceImpl` method `doB()`

```
public interface MyService {
    public void doC();
    public void doB();
}
```

This works but in eclipse when I click on `doB()` method (`doC()` works) in MyService Open Implementation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left mouse click) I can't find any implementation available  (see below)

Is it Eclipse bug? Is my setting wrongly constructed? is my expectation wrong?

[image]

- Note from `GeneralService` I can open implementation for its `doB()`  method
- Note another reason I need it is also to add a Spring Service support to existing method

Comment: Which word in which line of the code you posted, are you clicking on with the mouse?

Comment: @Abra `doD()` in `MyService`. Updated my question

Comment: Works for me with Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 7 with Java 8.

Comment: @Abra I'm using Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see **it is not a bug.**

Lets understand (I have made pictorial representation to understand better):

[image]

It is clear that the `GeneralServiceImpl` class overrides `doB()` function of implementing interface `GeneralService` as well as `MyServiceImpl` implements `doC()` function of its implementing interface `MyService`.

Also, there is inheritance relation between `MyServiceImpl` and `GeneralServiceImpl` --> `MyServiceImpl` extends `GeneralServiceImpl` , so `MyServiceImpl` has `doB(){}`.

Now we have to understand here that **IDEs, completion and compiler use the static view.**

If you want to know run time view then **one have to use debugging mode.**

So, if we see the way your classes and interface is designed there is no direct relation between `MyService` and `GeneralServiceImpl`, so `eclipse` is not aware of its `runtime` implementation and thus does not highlights the same.

Rather that dotted line in the diagram represents `runtime` relation and thus implementation of void `doB();` function.

---

Adding more info based on @howlger **comment** :

For an `Interface` implementing `class` should override all the declared functions (unless `abstract`). and as an IDE `Eclipse` when searching for an implementation of a function from `Interface` then it looks only for direct implementation in implementing classes. (like for `doC()` it works). [static view / compiler]

Now, imagine between `MyServiceImpl` & `GeneralServiceImpl` we have another class `SubGeneralServiceImpl` which also `overrides doB()` as

```
public class SubGeneralServiceImpl extends GeneralServiceImpl {
    public void doB() {
            //
        }
    }
```

and now `MyServiceImpl` extends `SubGeneralServiceImpl` and `SubGeneralServiceImpl` further extends `GeneralServiceImpl`.

So, even now `MyServiceImpl` has doB() **but now access to 2 doB() implementation** , which can be seen :

[image]

thus in static view (compiler) it is absolutely fine as far as `MyServiceImpl` overrides `doB()` & `doC()`...however Eclipse as an IDE is not sure which implementation is going to be used which comes at runtime, thus not able to give you the implementation of `doB()` when tried getting from `MyService` Interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not absolutely accurate. Whether a class implements an interface or not is determined at compile time, not at runtime. For example, `public class C { public int compareTo(Object o) { return 0; } public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(new C() instanceof Comparable); } }` returns `false`, but with `C implements Comparable` `true`.

Comment: The problem is that `GeneralServiceImpl.doB()` is only an implementation of `MyService.doB()` in `MyServiceImpl`, so displaying `GeneralServiceImpl.doB()` as an implementation of `MyService.doB()` would be wrong. There is no `MyServiceImpl.doB()` in the code that can be shown as implementation. It only exists by `MyServiceImpl extends GeneralServiceImpl implements MyService`. There is nothing that can be displayed even if it is known by static code analysis.

Comment: Hi, didn't get your point from 1st comment and I couldn't agree more on your 2nd comment as `GeneralServiceImpl.doB()` is the only implementation of `MyService.doB()`,as far as I see from the question, it is a beautiful case of `dynamic polymorphism`.

Comment: It might seem so, but it's not dynamic polymorphism. If you rename `GeneralServiceImpl.doB()`, you will get a compile error because in `MyServiceImpl` `doB()` is missing to implement `MyService`. That `MyServiceImpl` extends `GeneralServiceImpl` is fixed in the bytecode. The resolving of the bindings is done here at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: Hi @howlger , I have edited the answer with a sceanrio..I'd say thanks to your comments which made the answer more detailed ! Hope we are in sync now !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still believe that the binding is done statically and not dynamically here.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

Tested on:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

I also tested it on a fresh installation (no plugins other than the default) and it also works.

Also tested on OSX and Linux (no Windows available... sorry)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Neon

Comment: Tested the same in: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: It works on both Linux and Mac. Same code as before, same positive result.

Comment: @user7294900 Eclipse Neon (4.6) is outdated and has not been maintained for years. Please upgrade to Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11).

Comment: @howlger I updated my answer with a verified example

Comment: With the last update I can reproduce the same behaviour on both versions of Eclipse. And if I may, it is not Eclipse's fault but a fault in design. I understand you stretched a bit the boundaries to see what happens, but if this is a real world design I suggest revisiting it. The method doB() is correctly implemented in GeneralServiceImpl, in fact Eclipse finds it as an implementation for GeneralService.doB(). Since we are at design: all methods in an interface are by definition public and abstract so adding those keywords is a code smell. Conclusion: for me it is not a bug with Eclipse.

Comment: @user7294900 I see what you mean. In `GeneralServiceImpl` the `doB()` method is not an implementation of `MyService` even so it is used as an implementation in `MyServiceImpl` for `MyService`. IMHO showing `GeneralServiceImpl#doB()` as implementation of `MyService#doB()` would be wrong, but it would nice to have a hint that `GeneralServiceImpl#doB()` is used in `MyServiceImpl` as implementation of `MyService#doB()`.

Comment: @howlger you are right, actually I redesign the classes, but still the question remains

Answer (score 2):

**`GeneralServiceImpl.doB()` is not an implementation of `MyService.doB()`** but in `MyServiceImpl` used to implement `MyService.doB()`. Therefore, it would be wrong to display `GeneralServiceImpl.doB()` as an implementation or definition of `MyService.doB()`.

In the following example, annotating `FooImpl` with `@Override` leads to a compile-time error. According to the [Java Language Specification 9.6.4.4.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4) this means `FooImpl.foo()` does not implement or define `API.foo()`:

```
class MyClass extends FooImpl implements API {
    @Override // <- correct
    public void bar() {};
}

interface API {
    void foo();
    void bar();
}

class FooImpl {
    // @Override <- compile error
    public void foo() {}
}
```

Please note that there are more possibilities for non-explicit implementation/definition of methods which will not shown by Eclipse: for example instrumentation via a Java agent (e.g. used to mock objects) or via a declarative framework.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you do

> ctrl + mouse hover

, eclipse gives you 2 options:

a. Open declaration.

b. Open Implementation.

You need to select second option.

2. I would prefer to use

> 'ctrl + T'

to see full implementation hierarchy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I choose second option , but then it don't find implementations

Comment: Didn't it showed you MyServiceImpl in drop down? it's really strange as I have been using these shortcuts since I started java programming. Can you make sure you are in java perspective?

Comment: With updated example it becomes obvious that 'void doB()' is coming from GeneralService and MyService. I am doubtful if this is going to give you reliable results. How is MyserviceImpl expected to decide that doB() is coming from MyService or GeneralService? In reality, doB() in MyserviceImpl is from GeneralServiceImpl so, eclipse is not confused; it's the other way round :-)

Comment: I wanted to use existing (non spring) method in a new (spring) interface without explicitly call it, I redesign the classes, but still question remains because it works i.e. implementation is found in real time but not in eclipse

Comment: it works because jvm applies intelligence finds the correct implementation at runtime (not compile time).